# Decentralisation and Smart contract installation in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Please help me if my conceptualization is incorrect ---

Setup:

I am trying to understand how to achieve decentralization in Hyperledger Fabric - smart contracts. Assume Org 1 and Org 2 are in the same channel. Each of these Org have peers and endorsers. The endorsement policy is 100% of Org 1 and Org 2

Question:

In my understanding the SAME SMART CONTRACT needs to be installed in both Org 1 and Org 2 peer. In other words, So when a incoming transaction is sent to Org 1 and Org 2, the same smart contract is executed by both peers. 
Is this understanding correct?

---

REF: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/smartcontract.html

In the PaperNet network, the smart contract is shared by the different network participants, such as MagnetoCorp and DigiBank. The same version of the smart contract must be used by all applications connected to the network so that they jointly implement the same shared business processes and data.

---

If it is correct, the smart contract code must have been written by some developer (Possible Org 1 who originated the blockchain network),How is this decentralization?

I my understanding, In a decentralized environment, should not be there a way where ORG 2 can separately create its own smart contract and install and use that to validate / commit?

If this is possible, any articles / blogs that show how to do this?

As you can see te question is nothing to do with endorsement policies etc.

thanks in advance and please feel free to correct me if my basic understanding of decentralization is incorrect

Regards

VJ

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric is a DLT(decentralized ledger technology) platform. As from the word DLT, you may understand here ledger is decentralized. So, yes your basic understanding is wrong.

**Smart Contract:**

Its similar like to real world contract between multiple parties, on which all parties has been agreed(Like a property deed on which both parties i.e. seller and buyer will agree). Similar here in Hyperledger fabric, a smart contract is business logic, on which all parties(all participating organization, in particular channel) have to agree. So, you may say a smart contract will be written by some developer of any organization and all other organization can review the source code and will agree to use that smart contract.

**How it is decentralized:**

So, in every DLT, ledger is decentralized, i.e. each party will be having their own copy of transactional data.In Hyperledger fabric, each organization is having a peer that contains transactional data and world state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is quite strange that Ethereum like blockchain deployments do allow you to put their own smart contracts? Why did something as big as Hyperledger fabric would not do?

Comment: No, You are confused a bit, Suppose in ethereum there are two parties, org1  and org2 and they are going to deploy new token contract i.e. token1 and token2 respectively. So, now org1 and org2 both wants to trade in token1 then they have to use org1's token1 smart contract. Org2 can't deploy their own token1 smart contract. Same thing happen in all blockchain platform. Similar in Hyperledger both parties can deploy any no of chaincode but when they want to share information/asset, they have to use same contract.